# How to detect captcha on a web page using selenium c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, bots, recaptcha, captcha

I've created a fun little bot using selenium c# which plays tic tac toe on a site called omegle.com
and it works fine but it always gets blocked by captcha

So how do I check if a captcha exists on the page?

(note: I didn't say by-pass)

I've tried `By.XPath("...")` and `By.ClassName("...")` but it stops working after a while (maybe because XPath changes)

Here's what I've managed to make so far:

```
 public int captcha()     //detects captcha , 1= solved
    {
        try               //checks if captcha is on page and asks user to solve it
        {
            IWebElement temp=driver.FindElement(By.______("...")); 
            Console.WriteLine(temp.Text);
        }
        catch { goto end; }    //if captcha is not on the page

        Console.WriteLine("CAPTCHA DETECTED! Solve captcha to proceed!");

        while(true)
        {
            try         //keeps checking if captcha is still on page
            {
                driver.FindElement(By.____("..."));
            }
            catch { break; } //breaks out of loop if captcha is solved
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Captcha Solved!");
     end:;

        return 1;
    }
```

also here's the iframe tag:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LekMVAUAAAAAPDp1Cn7YMzjZynSb9csmX5V4a9P&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cub21lZ2xlLmNvbTo0NDM.&amp;hl=en&amp;v=UFwvoDBMjc8LiYc1DKXiAomK&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=t8ss8cm29p9u" role="presentation" name="a-f9qa6z183usf" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-storage-access-by-user-activation" width="304" height="78" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: It may be in an iframe. With out a link to the page, or a snippet of html, tough to tell

Comment: @DMart  i tried to take the xpath of iframe but it didn't work any suggestions?

Comment: Where's that code? Where is the sample html?

Comment: @DMart i added it now ,sorry i forgot to before

Answer (score 1):

The xpath should be:
//iframe[contains(@src,'recaptcha')]

Then you can check to see if the element is present by either using a try/catch block (on element not found exception) or using FindElements to fetch all elements and seeing if size is non zero:

```
Boolean isPresent = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'recaptcha')]")).size() > 0
```